# Receiving Error using Studio 3T to mongodump a localhost DB

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

While I try to use Studio 3T to `mongodump` a DB (MongoDB 4.0 version), I received the following error:

```
DB error writing data for collection `DB.posts` to disk: error reading collection: Failed to parse: { find: "posts", skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "DB" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

While I can directly `mongodump` from the terminal, I can't use Studio3t for my localhost. However, Studio3T works fine to mongodump or restore the same DB in MongoAtlas.I didn't have this problem on eariler versions of MongoDB (3.4 and 3.6) on my localhost. Is it something wrong with the Mongo3T setting or my localhost with MongoDB 4.0

P.S Tested on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. I fixed it by going to Preferences in the Edit menu. 
Select the mongodump tab and force it to use the correct executable.  Then restart Studio3t

[Preferences Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSOtK.png)